# Is there a way to turn off paclet updating altogether?

Tags: internet, paclets

We are running Mathematica 11.1 on a remote Linux box that has a pretty locked-down set of ports (enough for SSH and not a whole heck of a lot else), and it keeps trying to update things in the paclet manager, especially when we launch subkernels. This times out (which slows things down annoyingly), and we have a batch workflow set up in a way that makes the generated message very inconvenient.

Is there a way to just turn off the attempts to do the updates? I'm not even sure why it's being done for subkernels in the first place.

**UPDATE:** After poking around a bit more, I think the issue has something to do with the **master** kernel deciding to do a paclet update right after `LaunchKernels` is called; all the subkernels have the `-nopaclet` command line option, as they should, but starting the master kernel with `wolfram -nopaclet` causes the error and error message to go away.

Comment: That's weird because subkernels should be launched with the `-nopaclet` option. EDIT: In fact they are, you can see that with `ParallelEvaluate[$CommandLine]`. Did you report this problem to WRI?

Comment: Do you launch subkernels in the same machine, using the default method? Or do you have a special setup, with your own subkernel launch command?

Comment: Same machine, using the default method. See similar problems on Mac OS X and Windows.

Comment: Well, maybe that `-nopaclet` doesn't mean much, or maybe it is not handled as it should be.

Comment: Have you tried ``PacletManager`$AllowInternet=False`` ?

Comment: Just found that. It does the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open `Preferences > Internet Connectivity` and uncheck `Allow the Wolfram System to access the Internet`.

Alternatively you can set:

```
PacletManager`$AllowInternet = False
```