# Mathematica stuck in "running" for every calculation I attempt, kernel error

Tags: bugs, front-end, warning-messages, system, paclets

**Bug introduced in 11.1.1 and fixed in 11.1.1**

Bug was caused by a paclet update and fixed by a paclet update.

---

I downloaded *Mathematica* this morning to do an implicit polar plot. I attempt to run the code

```
Manipulate[
ContourPlot[ 
Evaluate@With[{r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], \[Theta] = ArcTan[x, y]}, 
{r Cos[Pi \[Theta]/(Pi - 2 chi)] - Exp[1/(r^2 Sin[Pi \[Theta]/(Pi - 2 chi)]^2- 1)] == 0, 
r^2 == 1}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}],
{chi, 0, Pi/4}]
```

This worked fine. I also wanted to plot the line `y==Tan(chi) x`, so I added that to the list (right after `r^2==1`). It did not work, and I got a strange plot. I closed that notebook, and opened a new one, to run the old code that *did* work. It no longer worked. After that, I started getting the following for *every single calculation I attempt*:

[image]

It just says "running" at the top, and never completes the calculation. It's not frozen. One time I got the following message:

[image]

I closed *Mathematica*, restarted the computer, and tried 1+1 again, and it doesn't work. Next, I followed the instructions on [this page](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464). When I try `$BaseDirectory` and `$UserBaseDirectory`, I get the same running issue. That didn't work, so I uninstalled *Mathematica* and reinstalled it. That fixed the issue, but then I went to run my code again and it did the same thing! So somehow this code completely breaks *Mathematica* to the point where I must reinstall? I'm at a loss.

Comment: I had similar problems today with MMA 11.1.1 and Windows 10. Then I disabled internet connection, deleted all files from the last few days in `$UserBasePacletsDirectory`, followed the advice to disable MMA internet connectivity given in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143386/42046) answer and re-enabled my internet connection. Now MMA seems to work and FrontEnd doesn't get frozen any more. But I consider this is only as a temporary workaround.

Comment: In case reinstalling doesn't solve the issue, try uninstalling and then deleting your [`$UserBaseDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$UserBaseDirectory.html) (default locations in that link, click on Details) before reinstalling.

Comment: It appears that Wolfram, Inc. has introduced a serious bug in MMA 11.1.1, which I first encountered late Saturday afternoon, US Central Time.  I reported it to Wolfram, Inc this morning.  Interestingly, 10.4.1 still works fine, at least on Windows 10 (64 bit).  The more people reporting this problem, the better.

Comment: Easier solution seems to be installing the previous version until they release an update fixing the bug.

Comment: I have the same problem with 11.3 Student edition. Even in 1+1 I am getting running!

Answer (score 20):

For a workaround, launch a standalone kernel and evaluate

```
PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[]

PacletUpdate["EntityFramework"]
```

More detailed instructions can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/mathematica-10-0-x-freezes-in-initializing-kernels) (except substitute `"CloudObject"` with `"EntityFramework"`).

Please see also [this post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1094350) on Wolfram Community for step by step instructions on all platforms.

Comment: This is very nice of you ! But why not fix the PacletUpdate mechanism once and for all?

Comment: For one friend this was not enough: he needed to evaluate `PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[]` first.

Comment: Thanks, updated. The linked previous answer has more detailed information.

Comment: I literally wasted 2 hours of my day reinstalling, cleaning, testing, etc. This is rediculous

Comment: This works, but of course I cannot accept it as an answer...

Comment: @0celouvskyopoulo7 Why not?  This is the answer to read for people who were hit by the same problem.

Comment: @maybe the issue should be called "Wanna Paclet" ...

Comment: The linked "post" does not exist anymore. Also I get:

"PacletUpdate::expobs: The experimental function PacletUpdate is now obsolete and is superseded by PacletInstall."

Answer (score 8):

I have a similar problem this morning. I open a new notebook and as soon as there is an attempt to start the kernel Mathematica freezes with the cell that is evaluating highlighted and "running."

I did a clean start and that did not fix the problem. I uninstalled and reinstalled Mathematica. Starting Mathematica, opening a new notebook, and evaluating 2+2 produces the same result -- frozen in the running state.

In this state Mathematica does not respond to an abort. So I am without Mathematica right now.

Is it possible Wolfram has done a paclet update that as broken Mathematica?

EDIT:

I moved the paclets directory (In win 7: c:/users/user/appdata/roaming/mathematica/paclets) to the desktop so Mathematic couldn't find it. Then turned off internet access at the OS, and started Mathematica. It starts normally and the kernel loads and returns instantly. Now, how to live without the internet?

This is cross posted [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1093197)

Comment: Interesting, so it's a waiting game? Should I email Wolfram?

Comment: @0celouvskyopoulo7 Definitely, YES! The more reports - the more chances this problem will be finally resolved. Notice that it isn't the first time we face such thing - it was in the past and was resolved, BUT apparently the fundamental cause of this still isn't fixed. So definitely report this to the tech support.

Comment: The problem above was on my laptop. I also have MMA on my workstation. I tried it there but disabled dynamic updating first and 2+2 worked normally. I then enabled dynamic updating and tried again. It is now also frozen. Both of these computers are running Win7 x64.

Comment: @DavidKeith Turning off dynamic updating after the freeze doesn't fix it for me. I'm running OSX Yosemite. Writing a support letter now...

Comment: @Shadowray I can't find anything like that (Base Directory) in the path they suggest it should be in, and I can't use MMA to check for it (because it freezes).

Comment: @Shadowray When I search in Finder, I can only find `~/Library/Mathematica`. The file `/Library/Mathematica` cannot be found. The contents of the ~ folder are [here](https://i.gyazo.com/519885c5482297538b2cbeccd5f208c8.png). I did the Option + Shift restart, and turned off my wifi. MMA froze on start.

Comment: @Shadowray Ok, deleting the whole folder worked. Should I try to rerun the code a third time?

Comment: @Shadowray Exact same issue.

Comment: @Shadowray I tried but when I delete the file I have to put in my product code again, this gives me an error unless I connect to wifi.

Comment: I figured out how to do what I wanted another way, but this is still a very strange bug.

Comment: @Shadowray   This continues to evolve. I do a clean start and I can't even open  new notebook. It just freezes. If I disconnect internet in the OS then I can open a new notebook, but if I try to edit preferences it freezes. Now I am getting kernel failed to start due to licensing issues. It may think thee are too many kernels running, but task manager does not show any. I will restart. I think this will need a WRI fix. I have reported it.

Comment: @0celouvskyopoulo7, DavidKeith I agree, this should be adressed by WRI support. I'm deleting my confusing comments.

Comment: @shadowray - Not confusing but helpful. There is a thread now running on this at the Wolfram Forum: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1093186

Comment: I found that abort with the first evaluation is only possible if MM had a connection to the "wolfram cloud". With or without signing in. Also it seems that when you don't evaluate a cell but try to first goto preferences the MM session hangs and I need to kill it with taskmanager

Comment: @0celouvskyopoulo7 I updated my answer with a fix that is working so far.

Comment: @DavidKeith Well, I got my curve smoothing program to work, so I don't think I need to do this. And living without internet on my laptop is certainly not an option :). If you hear back from tech support, please let me know though!