# How can I disable system updates only?

Tags: curated-data, customization, wolfram-alpha-queries, system, paclets

Suppose I'm quite happy with my current *Mathematica* installation and wish to keep the system in its current form just reliably working.

Since there were already at least two cases<sup>[[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146005/280),[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92931/280)]</sup> when a lot of people were not able to use their *Mathematica* installation one day or more due to bad updates, we have to accept that automatic system updates proven to be dangerous. Hence I wish to turn off this feature completely without disabling Internet access, curated data, Wolfram|Alpha, Wolfram Cloud etc. How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125199/38205) might help?

Comment: @b3m2a1 I saw [that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132781/280) but the conclusion "Nowhere along this tour do we find evidence of any fine-grained control mechanisms for this update activity." doesn't raise hopes. :(

Comment: So there's also ``PacletManagerEnabled[]`` but I dunno exactly what it does. I think a number of functions may also call `PacletUpdate` on their own--but you could always safely override that definition with via Villegas-Gayley in the Autoload directory. I also auto-generated some docs for the paclet manager. You can pull the paclet off [my server page](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-e4d1d43a-267f-4924-934a-2ba2321519a9/paclets/PacletServer/main.html) if you want to look through them.