# Can't Launch Kernels, Updating from Wolfram Research Server

Tags: parallelization, kernel-startup

So, I'm running Mathematica on an HPC cluster using the `math` module command line interface. I'm trying to figure out some problems with attempting to parallelize my code, and the following test code:

```
LaunchKernels[4];

Print["Hello world"]

AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 1000}];]
AbsoluteTiming[Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 1000}];]
```

Produces the following output (run with the command `math -run "<<ParallelTest.wl`):

```
Mathematica 11.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2016 Wolfram Research, Inc.
Updating from Wolfram Research Server ...
```

And then hangs apparently indefinitely. I know that this means that Mathematica is trying to load some paclet-based functionality, presumably for `LaunchKernels`, since it never makes it to the `Hello world`. What I don't know is a) why it never manages to load this (although I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that this cluster has limited, if any web access allowed) and b) how to make it not do this.

Comment: I have the same problem (but on a local laptop, while launching math with a command line ). have you solved that issue?
thanks in advance
I hope that I can write here this kind of question

Comment: Strongly related: [How can I disable system updates only?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146133/280)