# Standalone Kernel No input available

Tags: kernel, system

I have encountered the same problem as the thread attached. [Mathematica stuck in "running" for every calculation I attempt, kernel error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146005/mathematica-stuck-in-running-for-every-calculation-i-attempt-kernel-error)

However, when I try to launch a standalone kernel through Terminal (macOS), there is no input line available to evaluate the code given in the solution to the thread.

[image]

I have attempted a full re-download and reinstallation of Mathematica, but both problems persist. What else can I try to fix the issue?