# Kernel starts up very slowly on Linux

Tags: kernel, linux, kernel-startup, version-12, version-12.1

V 12.1.1, starting a kernel, e.g. by entering `wolframscript` in the shell, takes an unexpectedly long time (~5 min, the time elapsed between pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the showing-up of `In[1] :=` ); but the same operation for V 12.0 takes merely ~3 sec.

I wonder if I am the only one experiencing this.

---

**Update**

Also, inspired by @Ordinaryusers68 's answer, I find these two posts:

- [Is there a way to turn off paclet updating altogether? [duplicate]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143374/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-paclet-updating-altogether)
- [Paclets updating awareness and tracking](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125199/paclets-updating-awareness-and-tracking)

where, an option `-nopaclet` is mentioned when starting the kernel.

Comment: Thanks so much for bringing this up! I have similar problems since Mma 12.0, but I was to lazy to debug them properly. BTW, in my case this happens even when the system has a proper internet connection. For me `PacletManager`$AllowInternet = False' works best. I guess I'll put this into my init.m and update the paclets from time to time by hand.

Comment: Hi, @vsht , thx for your information. Actually, I had hesitated for a quite long time before I decided to put this post up. And I am really happy if it can help anyone. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don’t know if the problem you encountered is the same as the problem described [in this post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/749400). If the same, you need to disable automatic updates.

This failure is caused by the paclet update system. Just turn off this automatic update. The easiest way to close the update is to delete the "PacletSiteData_10.pmd2" file.

Comment: Thx for the response!

Comment: BTW, where is that file located?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ By using the [`Everything`](https://everything.en.softonic.com/) tool to search for the `PacletSiteData` keyword, I found that its location is `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Configuration\pacletSiteData_12.pmd2`.

Comment: @Ordinaryusers68 - +1 on "everything" - seriously useful tool.